# Flex : Displaying the Advanced DataGrid data in Pages

Tags: apache-flex, datagrid

I have a flex application where Im displaying login data using an advanced datagrid. Is it possible to show the data in this advanced datagrid, by a page wise way? if so do you have any sample coding to do this. thanks

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example I think might help you: http://gurufaction.blogspot.com/2007/02/flex-datagrid-paging-example-with.html

SWF: http://develop.gurufaction.com/App.swf

MXML: http://develop.gurufaction.com/src/App.mxml

Answer (score 0):

You can use the "filterFunction".
Write a custom function to filter data according on which "page" you are browsing.

Another solution is to split the original array to get several array which will be assigned according to the current page.